# JSON.parse not parsing Json string. Serializing with JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: javascript, .net, javascriptserializer

I have a serialized string comming from the controller to a view:

**Controller:**

```
var serialize = new JavaScriptSerializer();
return Json(new
{
data = serialize.Serialize(obj)
}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

**Json string:**

```
[{"indiceName":"Caracter","indiciId":24,"indiceId":1,"tamanhoIndice":10,"mask":null,"indiceObr":1},

{"indiceName":"Numérico","indiciId":25,"indiceId":2,"tamanhoIndice":10,"mask":null,"indiceObr":0},

{"indiceName":"AlfaNumérico","indiciId":26,"indiceId":3,"tamanhoIndice":10,"mask":null,"indiceObr":0}]
```

As far as I know, modern browser should be able to parse that string with a simple
Json.parse()

**View:**

```
success: function (data) 
         {
            $('.dinamic').remove();
            console.log(data);
            var obj2 = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(obj2);
         }
```

I am able to see that string in the first console.log, but I get nothing from the second.
Is there any thing else I should be looking at because all the post I have read people only do it as simple as it is with a single JSON.parse.
I am using latest version of google chrome ,firefox and IE so it should work.

Comment: What are you getting from `console.log(data);`? And what if you `console.log(typeof data);`?

Comment: The snippet under your "Json string" appears to be an array of objects, not a string. A lot of times `jQuery.ajax` (which it looks like you're using?) will handle the `parse` for you.

Comment: how is the success function called?

Comment: @Cerbrus : From data I get the Json string above, and the typeof says it is an object.

Comment: `Data` is already parsed by jQuery.

Comment: Yeap, just try to access `data[0]`, it should return `{"indiceName":"Caracter","indiciId":24,"indiceId":1,"tamanhoIndice":10,"mask":null,"indiceObr":1}`

Comment: @jbabey : It seems to be an array without index. I am able to send an List that arives as an object to the view, but this way I was not able to get the data.length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your `success` function is not shown in context of the other AJAX options being given, I would guess you are passing a `dataType` option of "json", or are using `$.getJSON` or something similar.

If that is the case, jQuery has already parsed the JSON for you by the time it passes it into `success` so you do not need to (and cannot) parse it again. You can simply use your data structure (`data[0]. indiceName` and etc).

(The below code is running live at http://jaaulde.com/test_bed/GuilhermeLongo/ )

Consider the following PHP (stored in *json.php*):

```
<?php
exit('[{"indiceName":"Caracter","indiciId":24,"indiceId":1,"tamanhoIndice":10,"mask":null,"indiceObr":1},{"indiceName":"Numérico","indiciId":25,"indiceId":2,"tamanhoIndice":10,"mask":null,"indiceObr":0},{"indiceName":"AlfaNumérico","indiciId":26,"indiceId":3,"tamanhoIndice":10,"mask":null,"indiceObr":0}]');
```

And the following JS:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $.ajax({
    url: 'json.php',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data[0]);
      console.log(data[0].indiceName);
    },
    error: function () {
      throw new Error('AJAX request error occurred.');
    }
  });
</script>
```

It results in the following outputted log info:

```
GET http://jaaulde.com/test_bed/GuilhermeLongo/json.php
    200 OK
    99ms    
    jquery.min.js (line 3)

Object
    {indiceName="Caracter", indiciId=24, indiceId=1, more...}/test_...eLongo/
    (line 8)

Caracter
```

Comment: This is the problem. Using jquery to have the job done, I set dataType to json and I get the string above. This is fine. But now when I try to get data from the parsed data: console.log(data[0].indiceName) returns nothing. I don´t have index ids [0], [1], so how I am able to capture itens by id?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "I don´t have index ids [0], [1]". The JSON you showed us is a serialized representation of an array full of objects. When parsed, you are left with a JS array which is automatically indexed 0-n.

Comment: The same example above I have data[0] set as: [Object {indiceName="Caracter", indiciId=24, indiceId=1, ...}, Object {indiceName="Numérico", indiciId=25, indiceId=2, ...}, Object {indiceName="AlfaNumérico", indiciId=26, ...}]. The diference is that in my controller I have a Json object passing as return Json(new { obj }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); where obj is c# List<t>

Comment: JSON is platform neutral. Once it's in JSON, if JS pulls it in it is a JS array and useable in the same way that any other JS array is.